# SQLAlchemy secondary relationship not using JOIN

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I created a Many to Many relationship on SQLAlchemy, but for some reason when I access it it's not emitting a JOIN clause, but rather selecting from a cross product of the three tables and filtering with `WHERE` clauses. I can't understand why it's doing this, and how to fix it.

Here's the python code for the association table and the primary model. The secondary model is overly complex and I think that the fact that it has `sku` and `account_id` columns which have indices (and together are part of the PK) is enough info to go on

```py
product_info_to_product_profile_association_table = Table(
    "tpl_products_to_product_profiles_r1",
    metadata,
    sa.Column(
        "sku",
        sa.String(128),
# This FK is failing at the MySQL level
        # sa.ForeignKey(ProductInfo.sku),
        nullable=False,
    ),
    sa.Column(
        "account_id", mysql.INTEGER(11), sa.ForeignKey(ProductInfo.account_id), nullable=False
    ),
    sa.Column(
        "product_profile_id",
        mysql.INTEGER(11, unsigned=True),
        sa.ForeignKey("tpl_product_profiles.id"),
        nullable=False,
    ),
    sa.UniqueConstraint("sku", "account_id", "product_profile_id", name="product_unique"),
)
​
​
class ProductProfile(BillingBaseModel):
​
    __tablename__ = "tpl_product_profiles"
​
    id = sa.Column(mysql.INTEGER(11, unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(90), nullable=False)
    account_id = sa.Column(mysql.INTEGER(11), sa.ForeignKey(Account.id), nullable=False)
​
    product_infos = orm.relationship(
        ProductInfo,
        secondary=product_info_to_product_profile_association_table,
        secondaryjoin=sa.and_(
            ProductInfo.sku
            == orm.foreign(product_info_to_product_profile_association_table.c.sku),
            ProductInfo.account_id
            == orm.foreign(product_info_to_product_profile_association_table.c.account_id),
        ),
        secondaryjoin=(
            id
            == orm.foreign(product_info_to_product_profile_association_table.c.product_profile_id)
        ),
        backref=orm.backref("product_profile", uselist=False),
    )
```

Here's the generated SQL when I try to access the relationship through an instance

```
>>> pp.product_infos

[SELECT product_info.sku..........
FROM product_info, tpl_products_to_product_profiles_r1 
WHERE tpl_products_to_product_profiles_r1.product_profile_id = %s AND product_info.sku = tpl_products_to_product_profiles_r1.sku AND product_info.account_id = tpl_products_to_product_profiles_r1.account_id]
[parameters: (6L,)]
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä yeah, maybe, but I want to know why SQLAlchemy is behaving the way it is and how to fix it, not whether the server will fix its shortcommings

Comment: @IljaEverilä okay, if you say so. The weirdness is that it's using the column instead of the value? I think I know how to fix that

Comment: I mean I agree there's maybe something strange going on; it looks almost like the instance itself is ignored entirely when fetching the product infos, and it's fetching all product infos of all product profiles. Edit: exactly, it should be using the value, as you say. And I suppose this is what you meant from the get go. Could you amend the question to include (relevant parts) of all models and tables involved? So that it's something others can pretty much copy, paste, and test.

Comment: yeah, I see that. I am having trouble with the dev DB setup right now and the table doesn't exist yet, tho

Comment: @IljaEverilä the primary and secondary joins are the wrong way around, fixed it in the post

Comment: Btw. instead of sorta fixing it in the post itself, why don't you write an answer? It'd be more clear for others what's the error in question and what's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best answer, but I've dug into some of sqlalchemy's inner working and it is explicitly creating the cross join when doing lazy loading

```
        if self.parent_property.secondary is not None:
            q.add_criteria(
                lambda q: q.select_from(
                    self.mapper, self.parent_property.secondary
                )
            )
```

The best solution I have found is to use eager loading of some kind.

Whether that's

- `lazy='selectin'` inside of the relationship definition
- adding `selectinload(ProductProfile.product_infos)` when querying for a ProductProfile object and know you will need to access that attribute
- or doing the same as above but explicitly defining the joins in the query and using `contains_eager(ProductProfile.product_infos)`

For the first 2 cases sqlalchemy suggests you use `selectin` or `subquery` eager loading when handling `x-to-many` tables (especially when the many table is large): https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#what-kind-of-loading-to-use